# ASP.NET MVC 5: is there anyway to get the client IP in the Global.asax file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.7.2

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application running on .NET 4.7.2.

We use DevExpress controls and add a lot of startup items in the `Global.asax` file in `Application_Start()`.

Some of the settings are adding are for error handling on their controls for unhandled exceptions etc.

I can't seem to find the right way to get the IP address. I understand `Application_Start()` does not track each request, but is there a way to do this?

I've tried this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the IP address.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>IP address</returns>
    private static string GetIpAddress()
    {
        try
        {
            string strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
            return System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(strHostName).GetValue(0).ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            return "IP Not Available";
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Error event of the Application control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var exception = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();

        using (var errorService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationService>())
        {
            errorService.CreateEventLogSync(new EventLogCreateDTO()
            {
                EventCategory = "Global Error (Application_Error)",
                EventDescription = exception.ToString(),
                EventLogDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                EventSourceDescription = $"{GetIpAddress()} | {exception.Message ?? "No message available"}",
                EventType = EventLogType.Error
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is what it generates when deploying the code and causing an error on our Azure instance:

> 10.0.3.30 | Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime

I understand this is a private IP address and not really want I to log when an error occurs.

So is there another way to try to obtain the IP address when an error occurs?

**UPDATE 2:**

It tried something like this by adding this code to a static class to be called from the `Global.asasx` file where I need to get the error:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the IP address.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>IP address</returns>
    public static string GetIpAddress()
    {
        try
        {
            string ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
            {
                ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            }

            return ip;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "IP Not Available";
        }
    }
```

[image]

But `.Request` is null and therefore throws an error.

**Update 3:**

I tried it directly in the `Application_Error()` call within my `Global.asasx` file but this is the error:

[image]

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Error event of the Application control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var exception = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();

        string ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
        if (ipAddress == null)
        {
            ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        }

        using (var errorService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationService>())
        {
            errorService.CreateEventLogSync(new EventLogCreateDTO()
            {
                EventCategory = "Global Error (Application_Error)",
                EventDescription = exception.ToString(),
                EventLogDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                EventSourceDescription = $"{ipAddress} | {exception.Message ?? "No message available"}",
                EventType = EventLogType.Error
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: The http request object should include those details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should be possible:

```cs
string ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
if (ipAddress == null)
{
    ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
}
```

First check [XFF header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) and if it's empty, check directly `HttpRequest`'s client IP address.

Comment: I tried that and it fails on `.Request. being null. Check my Update 2.

Comment: Your code in "Update 2" is different than my example. If you put this exact code directly into `Global.asax` `Application_Error` handler it works. `Request` can be null only in case that error was thrown unrelated to any client HTTP request. For example, application startup, or unrelated `static` methods or constructors.

Comment: check Update 3 now. Not sure why `.Request` is not available?

Comment: @ttest2727 Where does your `Exception` that triggers `Application_OnError` method occurs? Is it in `Controller`? If yes, you will have no problems. On the other side, if `Exception` is thrown, for example, in the `Application_Start` method, `HttpRequest` is still not available, because `HttpRequest` processing did not start yet.

Comment: YOU WERE RIGHT!!! Thank you. I was putting the error within the Application_Start call and not realizing `.Request`. Sorry. I was able to generate an error and I see the IP address and everything in error log in the db! Thank you!